# Point in plane closest to point

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find a point in the plane closest to a given point.
I have the equation of the plane, the point and the distance between them.
How do I find the point in the plane which is closest to the given point?

I have a tetrahedron with sides:
bcx=0, acy=0, abz=0, x/a+y/b+z/c=1 (a,b,c are not to mix with Ax+By+Cz=D in the planes equation, they are to be entered when running the script).

```
function [d n]=tetradist(x,y,z,a,b,c)    
if z>0 && y>0 && x>0 && z<c && y<b && x<a && x/a+y/b+z/c<1
        d1=abs(a*b*z)/sqrt((a*b)^2);
        d2=abs(b*c*x)/sqrt((b*c)^2);
        d3=abs(a*c*y)/sqrt((a*c)^2);
        d4=abs(b*c*x+a*c*y+a*b*z-a*b*c)/sqrt((b*c)^2 + (a*c)^2 + (a*b)^2);
A = [d1 d2 d3 d4];
B = sort(A,'ascend');
d = B(1);
point=[x y z];
if d==d1
    normalv=[0 0 a*b]';
elseif d==d2
    normalv=[b*c 0 0]';
elseif d==d3
    normalv=[0 a*c 0]';
else
    normalv=[b*c a*c a*b]';
end
end
```

So now I have the shortest distance, my point as a vector and the normal vector of the closest plane. Now how do I find the point in said plane which is closest to my point 'point'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are yo asking mathematically? Or how to do it in Matlab? If the former, then perhaps math.stackexchange is better, if the latter then please post some code and the equations etc...

Comment: In matlab, I can do it mathematically but the problem is that when I write a script to search for the points I try to search for it by looping through all points but since the point has some decimals the loops quickly get very nasty.

Comment: Post what code you have so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the equation of your plane is *Ax + By + Cz = D* and the location of the point is (*P*, *Q*, *R*) then the location in the plane that is closest to the point is

```
(P,Q,R) + λ * (A,B,C)
```

where

```
λ = (D - P*A - B*Q - C*R) / (A^2 + B^2 + C^2)
```

The following Matlab code calculates this point

```
function x = closestpoint(n, d, p)
# n is the vector [A,B,C] that defines the plane
# d is the distance of the plane from the origin
# p is the point  [P,Q,R]
v = (d - sum(p.*n)) / sum(n.*n);
x = p + v * n;
```